# Finding lines matching a pattern and extracting these into another file

Tags: grep

Search the file `data` for all of the lines that contain the pattern `linux`,
and put those lines in the file `matches`.

Comment: Copying homework exercises and potentially claiming the answers as your own may get you numerical credit on your course, but won't help you learn to apply the commands elsewhere in other situations.

Comment: ... not to mention the ethics of it, and the risk of your school catching and sanctioning you for plagiarism.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
grep linux <data >matches
```

The `grep` utility, by default, uses the first non-option argument as the pattern and will extract all lines that match that pattern in its input data.  In the command above, `grep` reads from standard input and writes the lines matching the pattern `linux` to its standard output.  The standard input comes from the file called `data`, and the standard output is written to the file called `matches`.

In the command above, the utility would not run if `data` was not a file accessible for reading or if `matches` could not be written to.  If `matches` does not exist, it would be created; otherwise, the file would be truncated (emptied).

In your question, the pattern is a string of *text* rather than a regular expression, which means that we may use `grep` with its `-F` option to possibly speed up processing slightly.  The `-F` option causes the utility to treat the pattern as a fixed string.  This is also the option you would want to use if you want to search for text strings like `U*ix`, where `*` would otherwise be taken as a special regular expression symbol.

For an arbitrary pattern string, you would want to use the `-e` option, with the pattern as the option-argument.  That way, you'd be able to search for strings starting with a dash, would you want to do so:

```bsh
grep -F -e linux <data >matches
```

If your pattern string represents a single *word*, i.e. a substring consisting of alphanumeric characters and/or underscores, you many want to use the non-standard `-w` option.  This would cause your pattern to *not* match `linuxes` or similar words.